# Is an atmosphere's oxygen partial pressure or concentration more biologically significant?

Tags: science-based, biology, atmosphere, gas, oxygen

I'm confused about the relationship between partial pressure and concentration of a gas, in relation to the biology of respiration. If I have a planet with high atmospheric pressure - maybe like 10 atm - but the O2 concentration is lower, maybe around 10%, what effect would this have on oxygen-breathing life? On Earth, oxygen makes up 21% of our atmosphere, with a partial pressure of 0.21 atm. In a 10 atm atmosphere, with oxygen at 10%, this would be 1 atm, which is higher than on Earth, obviously. Would an atmosphere like this provide higher or lower access to oxygen than on Earth? I guess what I'm wondering is, is partial pressure or concentration of oxygen more biologically significant?

Comment: Pressure and concentration are certainly related, but they also deal with very different aspects of physiology. A pure-oxygen low-pressure environment may provide enough oxygen for the body to live, but there are a host of problems that come from living at very low pressures. Likewise, the pressure can be high enough to avoid all those problems, but 100% oxygen at that point is toxic. So when you ask which is more significant, the answer is, "it's a curve. The curve is significant." You need the right amount of oxy at each point along the range of acceptable pressures.

Comment: BTW, could you explain why it's important to know a detail to that extreme? The likelihood of your story being read by people who would recognize a presented percentage as impossible is close to zero and human history has proven that if you write a good story people will ignore inconsistent or missing details while if you write a bad one all the details in the world won't save it. So if you don't mind, why do you need so much detail?

Comment: The Apollo missions famously used 100% oxygen at 0.34 atm (5 psi). There were no adverse effects on the astronauts. (Gases mix freely, and each component of the mixture behaves pretty much as if the others were not there; there is little difference between 100% oxygen at 1 atm and 10% oxygen at 10 atm -- and 1 atm partial pressure of oxygen is not healthy in the long run.) (But 10 atm is quite high pressure; I would start inquiring about the effects the *other gasses* at that pressure.)

Comment: 10 atm = 100m diving equivalent. You need special deep sea gas mixes to dive that deep safely. IIRC the main difference is that nitrogen solubility becomes an issue, so you use argon instead. Also, at all total pressures, including 10 atm, I think CO2 partial pressure is an issue in itself, not just the O2:CO2 ratio, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: @SeanOConnor - if you never surfaced, the N2 solubility would not be an issue since it would not want to come out as bubbles.

Comment: @JBH I'm making a fake scientific textbook/artbook, about how life might evolve on planets with different conditions. So it actually is important to me to get the science right. For most readers, it will be more of a coffee table art book, with the main point being the illustrations and the writing serving the aesthetic, giving the book legitimate textbook vibes. But I want the book to work on multiple levels and to be accurate for those interested in the science. So I really want the science to be actually plausible.

Comment: @JBH - What are the problems associated with low pressure if the oxygen is adequate for life? I'm exploring different habitable worlds for this book, and one of these worlds is a moon of a gas giant with lower atmospheric pressure. Hypothetically, if you have low atmospheric pressure (due to low gravity) but high CO2 (due to increased volcanic activity from tides), and that high CO2 allows for productive photosynthetic life, which produces enough oxygen to achieve a similar partial pressure to Earth, would there be any negative effects due solely to the lower atmospheric pressure?

Comment: @JonCuster That's true, unless they are temporarily exposed to low pressure (e.g. climb a huge mountain). Narcosis could be an issue, but I guess the vulnerability will be weeded out pretty quickly.

Comment: @AlexP - this is what I was thinking. But I'm also wondering, if this is true, why is respiration more difficult in water than in air? Oxygen should have the same partial pressure in air and water, but the relative O2 concentration is lower in water, which makes gas exchange more difficult. Would this be the case as well in a high atmospheric pressure environment?

Comment: @Elhammo Beware--low gravity worlds won't be able to hold onto their atmosphere in the first place, it doesn't matter what it is.

Comment: @Loren Pechtel - my low gravity world has high enough gravity to maintain a substantial atmosphere. It's half the mass of Earth, 75% the gravity.

Comment: @Elhammo That looks workable.  Note that atmospheric pressure depends not only on gravity but how much atmosphere there is.  Note that Venus doesn't have more gravity than Earth, just a lot more air.  The standard graph for what a planet can hold: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Solar_system_escape_velocity_vs_surface_temperature.svg

Comment: @Elhammo Allow me a clarification first: from the perspective of life evolving on your planet, the question you've posed is entirely moot. That we know of there is no limit to pressure or oxygen below which life is no longer possible. Remember, we have only one data point to work with, Earth, and sometimes we get too fixated on Earth. Now, if we assume (as I did) the purpose of your question was what would be the effect on *humans,* that's another matter. We're designed for a sea-level pressure of 1atm. (\*continued\*)

Comment: Lower the pressure too much and we begin to be susceptible to embolisms, capillary disruption, inability to absorb gasses through the lungs, hearing problems, and a host of other issues. We can grow to accommodate most of this (e.g., La Paz, Bolivia) and given generations of time spent in adverse conditions even adapt, but eventually the body's design to *push against the ambient pressure* starts getting in the way of living. However! I've been talking about low *total pressure,* not low partial pressure. Talking about (\*continued\*)

Comment: ... the partial pressure of oxygen is a waste of time because all you're really talking about is the amount of oxygen available to breathe. In other words, a low *partial pressure* of oxygen is simply a low percentage of oxygen in the total mix. So, as you design your worlds, remember there's a difference between the total pressure against the skin and the amount of oxygen available to sustain life.

Comment: @Elhammo, I've put thought into your earlier comment about your goal being a speculative but otherwise factual textbook. I don't know if we've encountered that purpose on [worldbuilding.se] before and I'm not sure it falls within the scope of what we do and why we do it found in the [help]. [I've asked a question about it on Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9907/40609) and I would appreciate you taking the time to think that question through and present your own views.

Comment: @JBH - I'm literally world-building, though. My project is not factual, it's fictional, but based on scientific principles. I'm designing a fictional planet, just like everyone else here. I really appreciate the help you've given me, but I don't understand why you would make a post to call into question whether or not I should be allowed to use this resource. Most of the time when I get answers here, I use them to give me clearer direction, as ultimately the main resources I'm using are journal articles and directly contacting scientists.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the Hyperbaric chambers for both medical purposes and treating decompression sickness. Some of the hard chambers go up to 8 atmospheres and include 100% oxygen , but with scheduled air breaks where the oxygen percentage is brought down to 21% to reduce oxygen toxicity.

The [Navy dive manual](https://www.navsea.navy.mil/Portals/103/Documents/SUPSALV/Diving/US%20DIVING%20MANUAL_REV7.pdf?ver=2017-01-11-102354-393) is interesting reading and there is quite a bit of we know this happens but maybe we don’t know why when it comes to oxygen toxicity.  As mentioned in the comments a lot of that uncertainty is suspected to be the role of the inert gasses. The tolerance to oxygen is higher when dry than wet for example. Why? Not sure, but you treat wet suits different than dry suits. Take someone off oxygen, and they go into convulsions why? Shrug, it doesn’t seem to be that bad and is like a “vigorous workout”. What is the role of CO2, it matters….  So it is pretty empirical document, but it has lead to a field of hyperbaric medicine. Some claims are probably unrealistic.

Heliox (mixtures of helium and oxygen) are used for two reasons medically there is less resistance when breathing so that helps with breathing difficulty in a medical context. It also prevents nitrogen narcosis or rapture of the deep and the anesthetic nature of inert gas.

Trimix is cheaper, and has enough helium to minimize the chance for narcosis.

So for your planet, it seems that you have some license to have some realistic leeway with the oxygen percentages and the effects on people and how they respond.

With the partial pressure you also have some influence on how flammable things are. But around 21 percent that shouldn’t be that big a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's the partial pressure that matters for biological processes.  There is a minimum pressure of oxygen you need to live.  There is a somewhat higher total pressure you need to live because at the minimum oxygen pressure you get too much water evaporation in the lungs.

Otherwise, all that matters is toxicity and stability.  (You can, for example, breathe perfectly well in 20kPa O2 and 80 kPa H2 but one spark and everything goes boom.)  Everything you could breathe has a point where it becomes dangerous.  Deep sea diving reaches a depth limit not because of what the pressure does to a person, but what you can breathe.